# Get initials of column c#

Tags: c#, string, removing-whitespace

I'm reding a .txt file that contains a list of several names in one single column, they are listed like this:

```
Lastname Middlename Name:
Lastname Middlename Name:
Lastname Middlename Name:
Lastname Middlename Name:
Lastname Middlename Name:
```

I only want to keep the initials of every name and add them to another list, for example:

Lastname Middlename Name: => LAMN

Do I have to separate by spaces? or use several removes? or use RegEX?
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest having only *one* list of "People", and providing an accessor for their initials.

Comment: Pick your poison.  You may split the string using native string functions or you may use RegEx.  I suspect there is more to the question :)

Comment: Where does that `A` come from?

Comment: @Oded I need to get the firt two words from the lastname, the first of the middle name and the first one of name.

Comment: I suggest that examples with actual inputs and required outputs would have been easier to understand...

Comment: @NominSim How can I provide and accesor for the initials?

Comment: @carloscarbajal I added it as an answer. The idea is that you usually don't want to have to worry about separate lists for the same data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt")
             .Select(line => new string (line.Split(' ')
                            .Select(s => s.First())
                            .ToArray())
               ).ToList();
```

---

**Edit:**

To get two letters from last name:

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt").Select(line =>
            {
                var words = line.Split(' ');
                var la = words.First().Take(2);
                var mn = words.Skip(1).Select(s => s.First());

                return new string(la.Concat(mn).ToArray()).ToUpper();
            }
           ).ToList();
```

The result with be: LAMN

Comment: Hi Cuong Le, I already read the lines of a .txt file and save only the first column of names into my listbox, but the problem is to save only the initials of this names into another listbox. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! if I want to use another var called "n" how it would be in this coode, because I have Lastname, Middlename and name. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @carloscarbajal: you dont need to, because, "mn" in here covers both MiddleName and nam

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Person> ParseFile(string filePath)
{
    List<Person> lp = new List<Person>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            lp.Add(new Person(sr.ReadLine()));
        }
    }
    return lp;
}
```

With

```
class Person
{
    public Person(string fullName)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    private string fullName;
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return fullName; }
        set { fullName = value; }
    }
    private string initials;

    public string Initials
    {
        get { return String.Join("",new string[]{
            String.Join("",fullName.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Take(1).Select(i => i.Substring(0, 2))),
            String.Join("",fullName.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Skip(1).Select(i => i.Substring(0, 1)))
        });
        set { initials = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would make a Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    string _initials = "";
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; private set; }
    public String MiddleName { get; private set; }
    public String Initials { get { return _initials; } }
    public String FullName { get { return FirstName + MiddleName + LastName; } }

    public Person(String name)
    {
        string[] names = name.Split(' ');
        if (names.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect format for a person.");
        }
        FirstName = names[2];
        MiddleName= names[1];
        LastName  = names[0];
        _initials = 
             String.Concat(LastName[0],LastName[1],MiddleName[0],FirstName[0]);
    }
}
```

Then populate the Person class with the file:

```
List<Person> personsList = new List<Person>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        Person p = new Person(reader.ReadLine());
        personsList.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Then you can access the Person's first,last,and middle name as well as their initials:

```
foreach(Person p in personsList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Initials);
}
```

Comment: +1 FYI there was an edit in the comments, OP wants first two initials of last name.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's not a complete solution for your question, but I think is the better way to get initials without using LINQ.

[Regex to extract initials from Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820273/regex-to-extract-initials-from-name#answer-10821419)